# How to compute value of i-th digit in a k-ary representation of a number? 

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers

What is a good algorithm to compute the value of the *i*-th digit in a *k*-ary representation of a number *n*?

Example:

For function `bitval(int k, int i, int n)`:

`bitval(5, 4, 9730) = 2` because in a 5-ary (quinary) representation of the number 9730 (which is 302410) the 4th digit (from the right) is 2.

Comment: What is "t" in your question title?

Comment: @Oli: Sorry, just had hit 'submit' too early...

Comment: @Kerrek: I don't see your point. `n` is a number, e.g. 9730, not a string representation. You have a point though if you really mean that the function should _return_ a string, e.g. "f" if k=16 (hexadecimal representation).

Comment: @Frank: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you wanted the binary digit in a number given by a string in a certain base. I think your question should just say "compute the ith *digit*", that's the more common term. "Bit" really means "binary digit".

Comment: @Frank: Thanks, changed "bit" to "digit".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
(n / (k ** i)) % k
```

(where `**` is the exponentiation operator and `/` is integer (truncating) division) should do it. Use `(i-1)` if you want to number the digits from the right starting with 1 rather than starting with 0.

Answer (score -2):

The naive algorithm is as follows:

1. Calculate the `k`-ary representation of `n`.  This can be achieved with repeated divides and modulo operations.
2. Return the `i`-th digit in this representation.